# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What are the most common reasons for (synchronic) word-order changes in isolating languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/what-are-the-most-common-reasons-for-synchronic-word-order-changes-in-isolatin)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How do directional morphemes work independant of relative positions of the speaker and listener?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4066/how-do-directional-morphemes-work-independant-of-relative-positions-of-the-speak)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why did England not maintain French as a spoken language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4178/why-did-england-not-maintain-french-as-a-spoken-language)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why does the Georgian adverb მწარედ (mtsared) "bitterly" end in -ედ rather than -ად?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4069/why-does-the-georgian-adverb-mtsared-bitterly-end-in-rather-than)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Does language improve over time, or does it just change?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4080/does-language-improve-over-time-or-does-it-just-change)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is there any proof that diphthongs exist?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4186/is-there-any-proof-that-diphthongs-exist)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Across ergative languages, is there a case that typically marks arguments in copular & existential clauses?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/across-ergative-languages-is-there-a-case-that-typically-marks-arguments-in-cop)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is "soon" in "it is soon" a predicative adverb or adjective or both?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/is-soon-in-it-is-soon-a-predicative-adverb-or-adjective-or-both)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Are the meanings of «I know what you know» distinguishable?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4142/are-the-meanings-of-i-know-what-you-know-distinguishable)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the difference, if any, between "ungrammatical" and "infelicitous" as linguistic terms?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4196/what-is-the-difference-if-any-between-ungrammatical-and-infelicitous-as-li)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)